# AWS Glue: Add An Attribute to CSV Distinguish Between Data Sets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I need to pull two companies' data from their respective AWS S3 buckets, map their columns in Glue, and export them to a specific schema in a Microsoft SQL database. The schema is to have one table, with the companies' data being distinguished with attributes for each of their sites (each company has multiple sites).

I am completely new to AWS and SQL, would someone mind explaining to me how to add an attribute to the data, or point me to some good literature on this? I feel like manipulating the .csv in the Python script I'm already running to automatically download the data from another site then upload it to S3 could be an option (deleting NaN columns and adding a column for site name), but I'm not entirely sure.

I apologize if this has already been answered elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I find [this website](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) to generally be pretty helpful with figuring out SQL stuff. I've linked to the ALTER TABLE commands that would allow you to do this through SQL.

If you are running a python script to edit the .csv to start, then I would  edit the data there, personally. Depending on the size of the data sets, you can run your script as a Lambda or Batch job to grab, edit, and then upload to s3. Then you can run your Glue crawler or whatever process you're using to map the columns.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I am exploring adding in editing the .csv to the Python script.